# Install packages that create home directory on automounted Linux servers

Tags: linux, debian, apt, autofs, automount

When installing certain packages, for example `gitlab-runner`, a directory needs to be created in `/home`/. If the home directories are automounted on NFS, then installation will fail.

$ sudo apt install -y [package]
Setting up gitlab-runner (12.1.0) ...
GitLab Runner: creating gitlab-runner...
useradd: cannot create directory /home/gitlab-runner
dpkg: error processing package gitlab-runner (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 12
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gitlab-runner
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What is the best workaround for this problem?

Have `dpkg` create the home directory in another location such as `/var`?

Answer (score 4):

The workaround I found for gitlab-runner is to manually create a 'gitlab-runner' user with a specified local home directory.

Comment: To be clear, if you add the user **before** installing the package, the package will not try to create the user under `/home`.